# How to log error in every class in asp.net web froms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, exception, asmx

I work on a big web from application, it has more than 300 web services (asmx) and more than 600 user control (ascx) which are loaded by Ajax requests, now I would like to make an exception handling system that saves error with the name parameter of relative department, because I want to understand this error is for which department.
Whether or not the exceptions are handled at the methods, I want to log them.
I think a good approach would be to use something like MVC filter attributes. But I don't know know how to do it in asp.net web forms.

Please forgive my poor English

Comment: This already exists. Use [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb398933.ASPX).

Comment: For those readers who don't already know: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: You're talking about attributes. Are you talking about PostSharp?

Comment: I don't have any experience with PostSharp but yes u r right I think it would be a good approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) which will add exception handling to your site with a few lines of code.  If you use NuGet, you can install the package via NuGet in the command of 
`Install-Package elmah`.

Scott Hanselman has an excellent post on it at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx